# Object of class set could not be converted to string

Tags: php

this is my php code

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class stripeContact{
    public $ID;
    public $amount;
    public $amount_refunded;
    public $currency;
    public $profileName;
    public $profileID;
    public $fingerprint;
    public $cardEmail;
    public $createDate;
    public $description;
    public $paymentID;
    public $logID;

}

class set{
    private $stripeOb;

    function __construct($input){
        $input = (array) $input;
        var_dump($input);
        $this->stripeOb = new stripeContact();
        $this->stripeOb->ID = $input["id"];
        $this->stripeOb->amount = $input["amount"];
        $this->stripeOb->amount_refunded = $input["amount_refunded"];
        $this->stripeOb->description = $input["description"];
        $this->stripeOb->logID = "-999";
    } 

    public function stripe(){
        return new log($this);
    }
}

class log{
    private $dbTableName = "stripeLog";
    private $client;

    function __construct($client){
        $this->$client = $client;
    }

    public function save(){
    // save to sql code
    }
}
?>
```

and in another php class im calling class **set** like this.

```
$stripe = new set($onlinePay);
$resStripe = $stripe->stripe()->save();
```

when i am calling this im getting this error

```
Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class set could not be converted to string in
```

this error occur in this line

```
function __construct($client){
    $this->$client = $client;
}
```

what am i doing wrong. im passing whole **set** class instance to constructor in log class.

Comment: Just remove the `$` from the client variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $this->$client = $client;
        ^
```

Get rid of that `$`, everything else is fine. That Typo is causing an unneeded conversion which generates that error.

Answer (score 0):

You should change on how you name your classes. set is a reserved word in php.

example:

```
class setStripe {

}
```

instead of

```
class set {

}
```

Hope it helps.